# Why does indexing not working in pandas columns function?

Tags: pandas, indexing

[image: df.columns code not working.]

When I run this code, it seems that there is an error somewhere, but I can't find it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you might need `np.r_` for slicing ranges something like `df.columns[np.r_[1:3,4:6]]`

Comment: Does this work in pandas dataframe as well?

Comment: it works for indexes yes, take a look at the dummy code in my previous comment and try on your dataframe, bdw please don't post images , people cannot copy the example to try it, instead [please create a minimal,complete and verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *np.r_* to concatenate ranges of column indices and use them
in *.iloc*, passing e.g.`:` as the row index. For example:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:3, 6:10, 10:14]]
```

produces:

```
   Player       Span  Mat   HS    Ave    BF     SR  100  50  0  4s
0  A Vala  2014-2019   27  104  27.37  1082  68.29    1   2  1  58
...
```

Note however that column numbers passed after each colon are **not**
included in the output.